# Switching Assistant and Manager values in SharePoint User Profile

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, profile-sync

We have SharePoint 2013 and we have been having this strange issue, where we can user profile to show Manager and Assistant, which are OOTB user properties that are mapped to **Manager** and **Assistant** receptively. The issue seems to affect users who have both Manager and Assistant values.
For example, let us assume Jon Doe has the following AD attributes:
Manager: **Big Boss**
Assistant: **Helper**

When users search for Jon Doe they will see **Assistant value** as **Big Boss** and **Manager value** as **Help**

I did check **Synchronization Service Manager** and found out **MOSS_FULLIMPORT** completed-warning

[image]

If I look at the **Adds** or **Updates** and I click on the number next to them

[image]

And click on one of the added items I see the following:

[image]

Which is a strong indication that the values have been switched between Assistant and Manager, and when I compare the between the values from AD and SharePoint, I find out that they values were switched.